# How does this "while True" loop end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, suppress

Consider this code :

```py
from random import randrange
from contextlib import suppress

mybiglist = [randrange(1, 100) for i in range(1000)]
count = 0
with suppress(ValueError):
    while True:
        mybiglist.remove(1)
        count += 1
print("Count of 1's is : %d "% count)
```

I didnt put any break statement to end this loop.
I am unable to understand how and why does this "while True" loop terminate ?
It magically breaks when it sees that there are no more matching elements to remove !
How ?

For example:

```py
from random import randrange
from contextlib import suppress

mybiglist = [randrange(1, 100) for i in range(1000)]
count = 0

with suppress(ValueError):
    while True:
        mybiglist.remove(222)  # a number outside of the randrange, so zero occurrence
        count += 1
print("Count of 222's is : %d "% count)
```

correctly prints

```py
Count of 222's is : 0
```

Considering that count didnt even get to the value "1", it is clear that the list.remove() is causing the while loop to break.

But the documentation for list.remove just states:

> list.remove(x) : Remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to x. It raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

and I have already suppressed the ValueError. So whats happening here ?

The following variant **without suppress** does work as expected and end up in an Infinite loop.

```py
from random import randrange

mybiglist = [randrange(1, 100) for i in range(1000)]
count = 0

while True:
    try:
        mybiglist.remove(222)
        count += 1
    except ValueError:
        pass

print("Count of 222's is : %d "% count)
```

Comment: The `suppress` actually catches the exception once it has broken the `while`, but your `try, except` catches the exception still inside the `while`, so it continues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing an element that doesn't exist raises the error. The error will stop the loop, and since you suppressed it outside, the code continues after the suppression:

```
with suppress(ValueError):
    while True:
        mybiglist.remove(222) # element that doesn't exist, raises error
        count += 1
# ... code continues here
```

If you want the loop to continue, you have to suppress the error before it propagates to the loop:

```
while True:
    with suppress(ValueError):
        mybiglist.remove(222) # element that doesn't exist, raises error
        count += 1
    # ... code continues here
```

That means the loop will continue running even with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is suppressing the error that ends the loop.  Your loop eventually cannot remove another value from biglist and throws a ValueError which you have suppressed, and therefor the loop ends in a seemingly clean fashion for you.  If you remove `with suppress(ValueError):` you'll see the following: `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`